# cakephp pagination Next,Prev character issue

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, special-characters

I am having customized pagination in cakephp .

```
<ul class="pagination centerPaginate">
    <?php
    if($this->Paginator->counter('{:pages}') > 1) {
        //If disabled,then last para
        echo $this->Paginator->prev('&laquo;', array( 'tag' => 'li'), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled prv' ,'tag' => 'li', 'escape' => false));
        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '', 'tag' => 'li' ,'currentClass' => 'active', 'currentTag' => 'a' , 'escape' => false));
        echo $this->Paginator->next('&raquo;', array( 'tag' => 'li'), null, array('class' => 'next disabled nxt' ,'tag' => 'li', 'escape' => false));
    }
    ?>

</ul>
```

The characters i am going to insert are `«` and `»`   , I used 'escape'=> false .

On 1st page "Previous" Tab contains proper characters . But Next contains `Tag like &laquo` Not actual character.

On middle pages Tags contain `Tag like &laquo etc`

And similarly on last[image: Example] page , "Next" Character is ok but problem in Prev character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself ! :)

I added `'escape' => false` as 2nd  parameter along with `'tag'=>'li'`  in prev,next

```
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('&laquo;', array( 'tag' => 'li', 'escape' => false), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled prv' ,'tag' => 'li', 'escape' => false));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '', 'tag' => 'li' ,'currentClass' => 'active', 'currentTag' => 'a' , 'escape' => false));
    echo $this->Paginator->next('&raquo;', array( 'tag' => 'li', 'escape' => false), null, array('class' => 'next disabled nxt' ,'tag' => 'li', 'escape' => false));
```

Solution below works flawlessly. In `$this->Paginator->prev(` as 2nd parameter , we specify : if we are not on 1st page ,what should happen , so i gave argument as `'escape' => false` and it worked